# FragmentPagerAdapter always starts from the first page

Tags: java, fragmentpageradapter

I have a Fragment pager adapter with five fragments and inside the third fragment I want to call an other activity which sends a selected picture to the container. It works fine but, every time the picture is selected from the other activity and the pager adapter starts from the first fragment in the fragment-activity instead of third fragment-activity. Do I have to force the pager adapter from the other activity or should I change something in the fragment-activity?

**Code:**

**Fragment-activity:**

```
package com.example.android.womb_the_game;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;


public class Circulation extends FragmentActivity {


    ViewPager vp;
    public static FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(onSavedInstanceState);

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_circulation);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        vp = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapterViewPager=new Adapter_Circulation(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
        vp.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);


     TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vp);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

**FragmentPagerAdapter:**

```
package com.example.android.womb_the_game;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import android.content.Context;

public class Adapter_Circulation extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 5;
    Context context;


    public Adapter_Circulation(FragmentManager fm, Context c) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = c;

    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return Frg0.newInstance (); 
            case 1:
                return Frg1.newInstance(); 
            case 2:
                return Frg2.newInstance(); 
            case 3:
                return Frg3.newInstance(); 
            case 4:
                return Frg4.newInstance(); 
        }
        return null; //does not happen
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS; //three fragments
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "RULES";
            case 1:
                return "EVENTS";
            case 2:
                return "PLAN";
            case 3:
                return "SHOOT";
            case 4:
                return "JUMP";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Fragment3**:

```
package com.example.android.womb_the_game;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Frg3 extends Fragment{

    private ImageButton shoot;
    private ImageButton snipe;
    private ImageButton aim;

    public static Frg3 newInstance() {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        Frg3 fragment = new Frg3();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frg3, container, false);
        shoot = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shoot);
        snipe = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.snipe);
        aim = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.aim); 

        final View.OnClickListener mListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.shoot:
                        FragmentManager FM0 = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction FT0 = FM0.beginTransaction();
                        frg_shoot F10 = new frg_shoot();
                        FT0.add(R.id.fragment_container1, F10);
                        FT0.replace(R.id.fragment_container1, F10);
                        FT0.commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.snipe:
                        FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
                        frg_snipe F1 = new frg_snipe();
                        FT.add(R.id.fragment_container1, F1);
                        FT.replace(R.id.fragment_container1, F1);
                        FT.commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.aim:

                        FragmentManager FM1 = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction FT1 = FM1.beginTransaction();
                        frg_aim F11 = new frg_aim();
                        FT1.add(R.id.fragment_container1, F11);
                        FT1.replace(R.id.fragment_container1, F11);
                        FT1.commit();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        rootView.findViewById(R.id.shoot).setOnClickListener(mListener);
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.snipe).setOnClickListener(mListener);
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.aim).setOnClickListener(mListener);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**Other Activity:**

```
package com.example.android.womb_the_game;


import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class choose_dice_column extends FragmentActivity {


   private ImageButton b1;
   private ImageView im1;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_dice_column);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

      b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b1);
      im1 = findViewById(R.id.im1);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent i = new Intent(choose_dice_column.this, Circulation.class);
                i.putExtra("resid1",R.drawable.n1);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, whenever you get back to your activity, you are creating a new adapter. So add the following to your `Circulation`-Activity to keep the state of the adapter:

```
if(adapterViewPager == null)
{
    adapterViewPager = new Adapter_Circulation(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I do that, all the contents of my fragments vanish and only the tabs remain. Also, when I add a button to the Circulation-activity next to the viewpager, click on it to another activity, then from the other activity to the Circulation class (to check, where the viewpager currently is), the tabs start from the first tab again.

Comment: Could you please change the part of my code, so that I can see, how it should look like? Maybe I misunderstood something. Thank you!